# downloading array of urls in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm creating a chrome extension. i have an array of urls and i want to download them all one by one, **one at a time** (meaning the second download will start only after the first one finished etc...)

i've tried this: ("links" is the array)

```js
function doDownloads(links, iterator, max) {
 chrome.downloads.download({
  url: links[iterator],
  saveAs: false
 }, function(downloadId) {
  if (iterator < max)
   chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function goToNextDL(delta) {
    if (delta.id == downloadId)  {
     chrome.downloads.onChanged.removeListener(goToNextDL);
     if (delta.state && delta.state.current  === 'complete' && iterator + 1 < max)
      doDownloads(links, iterator + 1, max);
    } 
   });
 });
}
```

but it doesn't work ):

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more tries, I got the solution to my problem.
Here is the correct code:

```js
function doDownloads(links, iterator, max) {
 chrome.downloads.download({
  url: links[iterator],
  saveAs: false
 }, function(downloadId) {
  if (iterator < max + 1)
  var goToNextDL = function(delta) {
   if ((delta.id == downloadId)  && (delta.state) && (delta.state.current != "in_progress")) {
    chrome.downloads.onChanged.removeListener(goToNextDL);
    if (delta.state.current  === 'complete')
     doDownloads(links, iterator + 1, max);
   }
  };
  chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(goToNextDL);
 });
}


var array_of_links = [...];
doDownloads(array_of_links, 0, array_of_links.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
var Dest=''; 

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
 Dest='image'+i+'.jpg';
 chrome.downloads.download({url:links[i] ,filename:Dest, conflictAction:'overwrite'});

}
```

NB: I've added simple logic for changing the destination file name.

Comment: this will make all the urls be downloaded at the same time, that's what i'm trying to avoid...

Comment: You can encapsulate each DL like this... setTimeout(function(){ // DL in here},2500);

Comment: the server itself allows me to download only one file at a time, so i have to check somehow the state of the download, and a listener seems to be the best solution

Comment: so just waiting fot 2500 ms doesnt solve the problem

Comment: I tried to update the answer with the delay for each DL but the message kept breaking.

Comment: Isn't there a chrome.onCompletedDL something or other function in the APIs that can tell you when each DL is done... I seem to recall something to that effect.

Comment: that's what i was trying to get using the addListener and removeListener.. didn't work, don't know why

Answer (score 0):

How's this method?

```
var Counter=0; // global var




function DownloadURL(URL){

var DL=new XMLHttpRequest();

DL.onload=function(evt){var arraybuffer=DL.response;};

DL.addEventListener('load', function(evt){ Counter++; if(Counter<Links.length){DownloadURL(Links[Counter]);} });  // increment to next file

DL.open('GET',URL,true);

DL.responseType='arraybuffer';

DL.send();

}
```

Call it once to get the ball rolling...

```
DownloadURL(Links[Counter]);
```

Comment: you cant use Counter that way, you're inside a callback, that won't have any effect

Comment: Ah well, you gotta bury your head into the DL Chrome API and get it right. :)